# Non-restrictive email validation

Tags: javascript, jquery

Just looking to do some super-duper basic email validation and was wondering if my code is efficient.

IE8 compatibility is a requirement.

```
/**
 * Email validation is futile
 * Make sure the @ symbol is not the first or last character
 */
jQuery.validator.addMethod("easyEmail", function(value, element, param) {
    value = $.trim(value);
    return this.optional(element) || (value.indexOf('@') > 0 && value.charAt((value.length-1)) !== '@');
}, "Please enter a valid email address.");
```

I am trying not to step on any toes since the RFC is mind-bogglingly complicated.

Comment: Hmmm, `email` is a valid email address then, since you do not check for the @ sign ?

Comment: @MonkeyZeus change that to `value.indexOf('@') > 0` and remove the silly `!== '@'` to hit two birds with one stone ;-)

Comment: http://www.regular-expressions.info/email.html one of those will count as good enough (There's also various threads on stackoverflow)

Comment: Seeing as you're using jQuery validate, why not just use the `email: true` option when validating email addresses? The relevant code is here: https://github.com/jzaefferer/jquery-validation/blob/master/src/core.js#L1108-L1114

Comment: @user45891 Yes there are various threads on Stackoverflow which basically concur that it is futile to regex an email and maintain RFC compliance so why are you pointing me to regex? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/201323/using-a-regular-expression-to-validate-an-email-address

Comment: @Ben please read my comment to user45891

Comment: @MonkeyZeus If you take a look at the link it has a regex that CLAIMS to be fully compliant (I seriously cannot be bothered to check it - I mean just look at that) but I think the key phrase was "good enough".

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your code would be slightly nicer this way:

```
jQuery.validator.addMethod("easyEmail", function(value, element, param) {
    if (this.optional(element)) {
        return true;
    }
    var trimmed = $.trim(value);
    var index = trimmed.indexOf('@');
    return index > 0 && index < trimmed.length - 1;
}, "Please enter a valid email address.");
```

Slightly nicer, because:

- Check `element` before trimming `value`, as you might not use `value` at all.
- It's a good practice to not overwrite parameter variables
- It's good to cache the result of `.indexOf` to avoid calling twice

That said, since [@user45891](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/users/49131/user45891) found that [nice link](http://www.regular-expressions.info/email.html) for you, I recommend you use it. I understand you only want a super-simple email validation, but this is waaaay too simple, to the point of almost uselessness.